# How to prevent unexpected validation in vee-validate?

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I've two fields: **unique** and **unique1**. Both fields are validate on blur.

**unique** is required.

**unique1** have three rules - required, speicalRule and is_not: unique.

**The problem:**

When I type something in **unique1** - the behavior of validator is logical.
And then after I start to type something in **unique** - the speicalRule *fires each time **on change** unique field.*

**The question:**

How to prevent unexpected validation rule "speicalRule" in vee-validate?

Here is the code:

```
<input name="unique" data-vv-validate-on="blur" placeholder="unique" v-validate="'required'" v-model="unique">

<input name="unique1" data-vv-validate-on="blur" placeholder="unique1" v-validate="{required:true,speicalRule: true, is_not: unique }" v-model="unique1">

mounted() {
const speicalRule = function speicalRule(unique1) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
     debugger;
      return resolve({
        valid: true, //this is specical for test and demonstrate the problem
        data: {
          message: 'incorrect'
        }
      })
    });
};

this.$validator.extend("speicalRule", {
    validate: speicalRule,
    getMessage: function getMessage(field, params, data) {
        return data.message;
    }
});
```

}

Example you can have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/e3u2br9v/

Answer (score 1):

In the **unique1** field, there is a rule **is_not**, where you are passing the value of **unique** as a parameter. Now, whenever the value of **unique** is changed, the **unique1** field is validated. Thus, all the associated rule to **unique1** is verified. That's why **specialRule** is fired.

If this validation is unexpected, you may remove the dependency between two fields.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ATT's answer, see this documentation about interaction modes: https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/interaction.html#interaction-modes

If you dislike how validation is so aggressive, consider switching to a different mode.